# Find a value from a table to match in a form - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have an Employees table with all of the employee ID and let's say there is a form to report an employee. The form asks for the Employee ID and details. I want it so the form cannot be submitted if the employee id isn't in the Employees table.

I tried:

```
If [Forms]![ReportEmployee]![EmployeeID] <> [Employees]![EmployeeID] Then
  MessageBox: Error!
  StopMacro.
```

Comment: Instead of an empty box for users to fill in, add a combobox that contains all of the current IDs so users can only select IDs that exist.

Comment: Any luck? did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up a value and see if it's null, so use `IsNull` and `DLookup`.

I don't know macros but you could try something like this:

```
If IsNull(DLookup("EmployeeID", "Employees", "EmployeeID = " & _
    [Forms]![ReportEmployee]![EmployeeID])) Then
        MessageBox: Error!
        StopMacro.
```

Comment: See my comment on your original post and do that if possible. You always want to guarantee successful input when possible instead of checking for errors.